Build failed continuously in react native while launching on emulater
Getting this error continuously and even after trying so much couldn't solve it.
Here are the error logs
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:buildCMakeDebug[x86_64]'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: ninja: Entering directory `C:\Projects\Nirlat\android\app\.cxx\Debug\2n5b1y2q\x86_64'
  
  C++ build system [build] failed while executing:
      @echo off
      "C:\\Users\\sit420\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\cmake\\3.22.1\\bin\\ninja.exe" ^
        -C ^
        "C:\\Projects\\Nirlat\\android\\app\\.cxx\\Debug\\2n5b1y2q\\x86_64" ^
        appmodules ^
        react_codegen_rnscreens ^
        react_codegen_rnsvg ^
        react_codegen_safeareacontext
    from C:\Projects\Nirlat\android\app
  ninja: error: exception: 0xC0000005
  ninja: warning: minidump created: C:\Users\sit420\AppData\Local\Temp\\ninja_crash_dump_4100.dmp

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-gesture-handler:mergeDebugAndroidTestNativeLibs'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeNativeLibsTask$MergeNativeLibsTaskWorkAction
   > 2 files found with path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so' from inputs:
      - C:\Projects\Nirlat\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\build\intermediates\library_jni\debug\copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly\jni\arm64-v8a\libc++_shared.so
      - C:\Users\sit420\.gradle\caches\8.9\transforms\fbf9b5a7055ce2465909adf37dc84594\transformed\react-android-0.76.1-debug\jni\arm64-v8a\libc++_shared.so
     If you are using jniLibs and CMake IMPORTED targets, see
     https://developer.android.com/r/tools/jniLibs-vs-imported-targets

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-screens:mergeDebugAndroidTestNativeLibs'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeNativeLibsTask$MergeNativeLibsTaskWorkAction
   > 2 files found with path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libfbjni.so' from inputs:
      - C:\Projects\Nirlat\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\build\intermediates\library_jni\debug\copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly\jni\arm64-v8a\libfbjni.so
      - C:\Users\sit420\.gradle\caches\8.9\transforms\fbf9b5a7055ce2465909adf37dc84594\transformed\react-android-0.76.1-debug\jni\arm64-v8a\libfbjni.so
     If you are using jniLibs and CMake IMPORTED targets, see
     https://developer.android.com/r/tools/jniLibs-vs-imported-targets

What I have tried so far.

Delete node modules
delete yarn.lock
delete .gradle and build folders from android
yarn upgrade
upgrade SDK manager and Cmake.

